# swipe hours calculation in data table directly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im working on a app where I have to work with swipe hours calculation. I have to generate a tool where it will take excel values and calculate hours for all employees in a month. I know how to handle this in sql server but I do not know how to handle directly in data table or dataset. can anybody please help me in solving this issue. uptill now my code so far is as follows.

```
using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            pck.Load(stream);
        }
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        System.Data.DataTable tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
        }
        var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
        for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
        {
            var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
            DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
            foreach (var cell in wsRow)
            {
                row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
            }
        }
        return tbl;
    }
if (Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".xlsx")
{
    dt = GetDataTableFromExcel(URL, true);
}
```

From here i will get the data table as below

`+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| Employeid |   Swipe dateTime    | Event type |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| A         | 01-01-2017 09:48:06 | IN         |
| A         | 01-01-2017 10:22:42 | OUT        |
| B         | 01-01-2017 10:22:56 | IN         |
| B         | 01-01-2017 10:36:46 | EXIT       |
| C         | 01-01-2017 10:37:04 | IN         |
| C         | 01-01-2017 12:52:57 | OUT        |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+`

now my task is to calculate IN and OUT hours and get the each employee working hours per day,week and month in data table directly.

Please help me on the same.

Comment: how this code is linked to you `Swipe hour problem`??

Comment: im fetching the excel data through this code and storing the data in data table. now this data table consists of empid,time,entry/exit. these three columns have all the data. now I have to convert them to swipe hours for a single day,week,month

Comment: you have not provided the enough details, what table structure what column what value. better then showing how you populated data into table, show us what you have in your datatable and what output you are expected from this data table.

Comment: nice to hear back, im fetching the excel values which are in the following format

Comment: the excel column values are        Employeid Swipedate Time Event type
A 01-01-2017 09:48:06 IN
A 01-01-2017 10:22:42 OUT
B 01-01-2017 10:22:56 IN
B 01-01-2017 10:36:46 EXIT
C 01-01-2017 10:37:04 IN
C 01-01-2017 12:52:57 OUT
   
   
   
Im fetching this kind of data into data table using the above function GetDataTableFromExcel(pathvalue,Boolean).

Comment: data table will get the excel data directly,my worry is how to calculate hours for every employee per day,per week and per month.

Comment: I have to deal only with c#,not with sql server. it can be anything not only data table,either it can be data set or ilist etc.

Comment: whats the difference between `out` and `exit`, do you mean need something like - `A -  0:34:36` and then for b - `B - 0:13:50` and for c - `C - 2:15:53`

Comment: out and exit both are same and data is something like you have specified only COLUMNS HEADINGS(EMPLOYEID-DATE-TIME-EVENTYPE) as A- 1-1-2017  -8:40:21-IN                                                    A- 1-1-2017  -9:40:36-OUT etc.,

Comment: so pls verify.. is this correct or not?  `A - 0:34:36` `B - 0:13:50` and `C - 2:15:53` these are working hours for each

Comment: yes those are working hours

Comment: so you need this??

Comment: of course Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so try to use the below method.

you may need to change some basic formatting or may be result table structure.

```
private DataTable CalculateWorkingHours(DataTable excelSheetDataTable)
{
    //Group all the data rows by user name and respective date
    var dd = excelSheetDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(c => new { name = c[0].ToString(), date = DateTime.Parse(c[1].ToString()).Date });


    //Create result table and some column in the table
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    result.Columns.Add("user");
    result.Columns.Add("work hour");
    result.Columns.Add("date");

    // loop all user and their respective date in - out
    foreach (var item in dd)
    {
        // for each user each day order the record by date time.
        var sortByDateTime = item.ToList().OrderBy(c => DateTime.Parse(c[1].ToString()));

        //first in record for the day
        var fIn = sortByDateTime.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c[2].ToString(), "IN", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        // if first in record for the day exist go further
        if (fIn != null)
        {

           // last out record for the day
            var lOut = sortByDateTime.LastOrDefault(c =>
            {
                return
                    string.Equals(c[2].ToString(), "OUT", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    ||
                    string.Equals(c[2].ToString(), "Exit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            });

            // if last out record for the day exist too..
            if (lOut != null)
            {
               // find the first enter date time, last exist date time.
                var fTime = DateTime.Parse(fIn[1].ToString());
                var lTime = DateTime.Parse(lOut[1].ToString());

                //add the new row to the result table,
                var r = result.NewRow();
                r[0] = item.Key.name;
                r[1] = (lTime - fTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                r[2] = item.Key.date;

                result.Rows.Add(r);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ok Deepak, I will try this logic and get back with accurate results, thanks for the reply and patience.

Comment: hi Deepak,it worked after some adjustments, it cleared the issue,thanks a lot.